# "Zend\Form\Element\Select" gets null value when I read data from form

Tags: forms, zend-framework2

I have a code which perfectly works (writes data to a db table) without Zend\Form\Element\Select. But when i put Select element in form the code doesn't work but also doesn't show any error message. It simply doesn't write data to the database.
So I tested controller code a little and here are results:

This is controller logic:

```
public function addAction()
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();

    if ($request->isPost()) {
        $this->postForm->setData($request->getPost());

        if ($this->postForm->isValid()) {
            try {
                $this->postService->savePost($this->postForm->getData());

                return $this->redirect()->toRoute('blog');
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                // Some DB Error happened, log it and let the user know
            }
        }
    }

    return new ViewModel(array(
        'form' => $this->postForm
    ));
}
```

First I tested data from request:

```
public function addAction()
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();

    if ($request->isPost()) {
          $data = $request->getPost();
          var_dump($data); 
    }

    return new ViewModel(array(
        'form' => $this->postForm
    ));
}
```

I got a array with accurate values. 'category_id' is Zend\Form\Element\Select.

```
  array (size=9)
  ... 'category_id' => string '4' (length=1) ...
```

Then i tested form:

```
public function addAction()
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();

    if ($request->isPost()) {
        $this->postForm->setData($request->getPost());
        var_dump($this->postForm);

    }

    return new ViewModel(array(
        'form' => $this->postForm
    ));
}
```

I got the same accurate result:

```
array (size=9)
... 'category_id' => string '4' (length=1) ...
```

Then i tested if the form is valid:

```
public function addAction()
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();

    if ($request->isPost()) {
        $this->postForm->setData($request->getPost());

        if ($this->postForm->isValid()) {
            echo "The form is valid";
        }  
    }

    return new ViewModel(array(
        'form' => $this->postForm
    ));
}
```

Yes, the form is valid.
Then I tested data from the form again.

```
public function addAction()
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();

    if ($request->isPost()) {
        $this->postForm->setData($request->getPost());

        if ($this->postForm->isValid()) {
            $data = $this->postForm->getData();
            var_dump($data);
        }  
    }

    return new ViewModel(array(
        'form' => $this->postForm
    ));
}
```

And I got the problem here:

```
... 'category_id' => null ...
```

I hope I was clear. Any help is more than welcome.

This is how my PostFieldset is defined:

```
namespace Blog\Form;
use Zend\Form\Fieldset;
use Blog\Model\Post;
use Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ClassMethods;

class PostFieldset extends Fieldset
{
    public function __construct($name = null, $options = array())
    {
        parent::__construct($name, $options);

        $this->setHydrator(new ClassMethods(false));
        $this->setObject(new Post());

        $this->add(array(
            'type' => 'hidden',
            'name' => 'id'
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'type' => 'text',
            'name' => 'content',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Blog Content'
            )
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'type' => 'text',
            'name' => 'title',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Blog Title'
            )
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Select',
            'name' => 'category_id',
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Category',
                'value_options' => array(
                    '1' => 'Gold Rings',
                    '2' => 'White Gold Rings',
                    '3' => 'Silver Rings',
                    '4' => 'Birthstone Rings',
                    '5' => 'Diamond Rings',

                 ),
             )
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code describing the form you use? Looks like InputFilter messes up the output.

Comment: Actually, I followed "Blog Module" from Zend Documentation http://zf2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/in-depth-guide/first-module.html.

And this is the form code http://zf2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/in-depth-guide/zend-form-zend-form-fieldset.html

My form code is exactly the same except that I put let's say one Zend\Form\Element\Select in Fieldset

Comment: more code needed like @raina77ow said

Comment: Please show how your PostFieldset is defined.

Comment: I've just put PostFieldset in the edited post.

Comment: I know It's very hard to fix problems without the complete code. I've just managed to put some code on github. Take a look: https://github.com/nesta-bg/BlogWrite